# QtCreator plugin -- name is missing

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I am trying to install a QtCreator plugin (this one, specifically https://sourceforge.net/projects/tabbededitor/)

I copy the files to my "plugins" directory but I keep getting "Unable to load plugins" dialog with "Name" is missing message.

What should I do to install the plugins?